# How can I share a footer control with another website?

Tags: javascript, html, css, .net, model-view-controller

I'd like to use a footer from one website in another website.

Visually, I can accomplish this with a page in the first website that displays only the footer and an iframe in the second website that points to the footer-only page. This is no good though because clicks in that iframe navigate that iframe, not the parent page.

What I really want is for the footer HTML (and styles) to be inserted into the DOM of pages in another website.

My only solutions are complicated. Does anyone know of a simple solution?

Corollary: Is there a way to grab a chunk of HTML from a web page with all computed styles inline?

Comment: What website are you trying to copy? Why are you trying to copy another website?

Comment: use HTML iframe.

Comment: try web components. for example: https://css-tricks.com/styling-a-web-component/

Comment: Web components is what I was looking for, thanks @deezg

Comment: @RyanWilson my employer has two websites and wants to use a footer from one on the other

Comment: @SabirHossain an iframe doesn't work for this situation because there are links and clicking those links in an iframe would redirect the iframe, not the parent page.

Answer (score 0):

There's a very neat library 'dom-to-image' that paints DOM elements on canvas and expose API to download said element as png/svg/jpeg etc.
What you should focus here is while exporting as svg, it creates a foreign object which is essentially parsed HTML with all the styles. You can very easily extract that foreign object by using simple string.replace and remove unwanted content and later append said HTML into your DOM using innerHTML.

dom-to-image https://www.npmjs.com/package/dom-to-image

Here's more reading material about Foreign Objects https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject